# Optimize Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker

Our frontends have such Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.12.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    apt-utils \
    git \
    xvfb \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libxtst6 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    libgtk2.0-0 \
    libnotify-dev \
    libnss3 \
    libxss1 \
    libasound2 \
    tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && \
    echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
WORKDIR /code

COPY ./ /code
RUN npm set registry <registry-url> && \
    npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm run bootstrap
```

As far as I can see it is not optimized because code copying happens before dependencies installation, right? And a better way would be to copy package.json and install dependencies first and then code copying? Something like this:

```
FROM node:13.12.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    apt-utils \
    git \
    xvfb \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libxtst6 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    libgtk2.0-0 \
    libnotify-dev \
    libnss3 \
    libxss1 \
    libasound2 \
    tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && \
    echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm set registry <registry-url> && \
    npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm run bootstrap

COPY ./ /code

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: This would be better off asked on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the most important thing related to Dockerfile optimization is to put the elements that might be changing in future versions of your container, the latest cause in case of any change on the code part, being the latest will not force recreation on other layers.

I think that's the reason for the Dockerfile to look like it does in your first example
There are other considerations regarding Dockerfile optimization that you can read for example here:
https://linuxhint.com/optimizing-docker-images/

Answer (score 1):

The `hadolint/hadolint` `Dockerfile` linter is a good starting point. Linting your `Dockerfile` using the [Haskell Dockerfile Linter](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint) i.e. `docker run --rm -i hadolint/hadolint < Dockerfile`:

```
/dev/stdin:5 SC2086 info: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
/dev/stdin:5 DL3008 warning: Pin versions in apt get install. Instead of `apt-get install <package>` use `apt-get install <package>=<version>`
```

... after fixing the issues and [sorting the packages alphanumerically following the best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments) with a couple of minor modifications your `Dockerfile` might look like:

```docker
FROM node:13.12.0

ARG NPM_REGISTRY

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-utils=1.4.11 \
        git=1:2.11.0-3+deb9u7 \
        libasound2=1.1.3-5 \
        libgconf-2-4=3.2.6-4+b1 \
        libgtk2.0-0=2.24.31-2 \
        libgtk-3-0=3.22.11-1 \
        libnotify-dev=0.7.7-2 \
        libnss3=2:3.26.2-1.1+deb9u2 \
        libxss1=1:1.2.2-1 \
        libxtst6=2:1.2.3-1 \
        tzdata=2021a-0+deb9u1 \
        xvfb=2:1.19.2-1+deb9u7 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    ln -snf "/usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ" /etc/localtime && \
    echo "$TZ" > /etc/timezone

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm set registry "${NPM_REGISTRY}" && \
    npm cache clean --force && \
    npm install && \
    npm run bootstrap

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Note**: the minor changes are by preference, i.e. `COPY . .` to `COPY` from the context into the `/code` directory which is set by the `WORKDIR` instruction.

Build the image passing the `NPM_REGISTRY` as a build arg i.e.: `docker build --rm --build-arg NPM_REGISTRY=https://yarn.npmjs.org -t so:66493910 .`

Comment: (That recommendation to pin to exact Debian package versions seems odd, since non-current packages get almost immediately deleted from the archives; hence the standard recommendation to always `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single line.)

Comment: I like it, fails fast when packages are updated. Can ignore the warning by setting `# hadolint ignore=DL3008` in the `Dockerfile` or in the `docker run` i.e.: `docker run --rm -i hadolint/hadolint hadolint --ignore DL3008 - < Dockerfile`.